# asp.net core razor page model public list variable resets to null onpost while string variable does not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm having issues or maybe i don't understand how this is supposed to work :) if so any help appreciated. So I have a blank asp.net core web project where i put together my issue see below code.  If i click on Submit1 button it calls OnPostSubmit1 and puts values into MyTestDetails List variable as well as tester string variable, then returns to page. If i then click on Submit2 button it calls OnPostSubmit2, if i debug at that point tester still has the previous value of "this is my test" from the OnPostSubmit1 previous call, but MyTestDetails List variable gets reset and has lost my values i set in it prior when i clicked Submit1 button and it called OnPostSubmit1. Just trying to figure out how i can get MyTestDetails to stick ? I have it set to "public" just like string tester.

Razor Page .cshtml

```
div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<form method="post">

    <button asp-page-handler="Submit1" type="submit" name="Submit1" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-hand-point-right"></i>Submit1</button>
    
    <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="@Model.tester" value="@Model.tester" class="form-control" />
    <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="@Model.MyTestDetails" value="@Model.MyTestDetails" class="form-control" />

    <button asp-page-handler="Submit2" type="submit" name="Submit2" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-hand-point-right"></i>Submit2</button>

</form>
<br />
<br />
```

Razor Page .cs

```
 private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        public string PopupMessage { get; set; }
        public List<TestDetails> MyTestDetails { get; set; }
        public string tester { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public void OnPostSubmit1()
        {

           
            MyTestDetails = new List<TestDetails>();
            TestDetails testdata = new TestDetails();
            testdata.test1 = "testing1";
            testdata.test2 = "testing2";
            MyTestDetails.Add(testdata);

            tester = "this is my test";

        }

        public void OnPostSubmit2()
        {
            foreach (TestDetails test in MyTestDetails)
            {
                string testing = test.test1;
            }

            tester = "this is my test 2";

        }
    }

    public class TestDetails
    {
        public string test1 { get; set; }
        public string test2 { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: if my answer helped you solve your issue, please accept it as the answer,which will help others who have the same problem to find the answer more easier.

Answer (score 1):

> Just trying to figure out how i can get MyTestDetails to stick ?

The most important thing you need to understand is that **the input hidden control can't store the value of list object directly**, which is why you can't get the content of `MyTestDetails` in `OnPostSubmit2`.

To solve it, you can get each set of data in `MyTestDetails` by looping `Model.MyTestDetails`, and *create two input hidden controls in each loop* to store the `test1` and `test2` field values under MyTestDetails respectively.

Here is the complete code in page:

```
    @page
    @model WebApplication1_rzaor_page.IndexModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
    }
    
    
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<form method="post">

    <button asp-page-handler="Submit1" type="submit" name="Submit1" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-hand-point-right"></i>Submit1</button>

    <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="@Model.tester" value="@Model.tester" class="form-control" />

    @if (Model.MyTestDetails != null)
    {
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyTestDetails.Count; i++)
        {
            <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="@Model.MyTestDetails[i].test1" value="@Model.MyTestDetails[i].test1" class="form-control" />
            <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="@Model.MyTestDetails[i].test2" value="@Model.MyTestDetails[i].test2"  class="form-control" />
        }
     
    }
    <button asp-page-handler="Submit2" type="submit" name="Submit2" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-hand-point-right"></i>Submit2</button>

</form>
<br />
<br />
```

Here is the test result:
[image]

Comment: brilliant! thanks for helping and providing a great reply. i see now.